# How to separate this code in two classes?

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I want to code a html scraper in c# which can get links or other targetted strings from the page I want to.

I just began and ran straight into a problem: I have no idea how to seperate the code in classes, so I can use different search engines.

This is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Scraper.Components
{
    class Scraper
    {
        public Scraper()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648)");

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(client.OpenRead("xxx"));

            HtmlNode rootNode = doc.DocumentNode;

            HtmlNodeCollection adNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='ad-title']");

            foreach(HtmlNode adNode in adNodes) {
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    adNode.Attributes["href"].Value
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My intention is to seperate the whole code below `client.Headers.Add` into an independent class, so I could call for example:

```
Scraper scraper = new Scraper(new GoogleSE('http://google.com/...'));
```

or something like that.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you're going to wrap a web client class I'd recommend wrapping HttpWebRequest to ensure you aren't locking yourself into Microsoft's limitations.

Comment: Why would you call a class `GoogleSE` **and** pass in `http://google.com/`.. wouldn't you just hide that in the class itself?

Comment: Because the URI can contain parameters, etc.

Comment: I think you'll find that the Strategy pattern and perhaps a Factory pattern will make your code very manageable here.  Please let me know if there is more I can help with.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Just a starter idea so far, but something like this should work.

This is the beginning of [the Strategy pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/52807/Design-Patterns-Part-1-The-Strategy-Pattern).  You may also want to look at a factory pattern for generating your search engine objects.

```
namespace Scraper.Components
{
    class Scraper
    {
        public Scraper(ISearchEngine engine)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648)");
            engine.Search(client);
        }

    }
    class GoogleSE: ISearchEngine
    {
        public void Search(WebClient client){
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(client.OpenRead("http:\\google.com"));

            HtmlNode rootNode = doc.DocumentNode;

            HtmlNodeCollection adNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='ad-title']");

            foreach(HtmlNode adNode in adNodes) {
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    adNode.Attributes["href"].Value
                );
            }
        }
    class BingSE: ISearchEngine
    {
        public void Search(WebClient client){
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(client.OpenRead("http:\\bing.com"));

            HtmlNode rootNode = doc.DocumentNode;

            HtmlNodeCollection adNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='ad-title']");

            foreach(HtmlNode adNode in adNodes) {
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    adNode.Attributes["href"].Value
                );
            }
        }
    }

    Interface ISearchEngine{
        void Search();
    }
}
```